# Google spreadsheet: Filter to get sum of row between matching pattern block

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a portion of daily run data below:

```
15/09/2015 00:00:00 STOP    
15/09/2015 00:15:00 START   
15/09/2015 00:30:00 START   
15/09/2015 00:45:00 START   
15/09/2015 01:00:00 START   
15/09/2015 01:15:00 START   
15/09/2015 01:30:00 START   
15/09/2015 01:45:00 START   
15/09/2015 02:00:00 START   
15/09/2015 02:15:00 STOP    
15/09/2015 02:30:00 STOP    
15/09/2015 02:45:00 START   
15/09/2015 03:00:00 START   
15/09/2015 03:15:00 START   
15/09/2015 03:30:00 START   
15/09/2015 03:45:00 START   
15/09/2015 04:00:00 START   
15/09/2015 04:15:00 START   
15/09/2015 04:30:00 STOP
```

A cycle will be defined between the STOP pattern, so that makes **cycle_one takes 1 hour and 45 minutes** as seen below.

What i have been doing right now is by using IF function i can get the time difference then for the last column i used SUM function. Then i manually identify each block pattern as cycle1,cycle2..

```
15/09/2015 00:00:00 STOP    00:00:00    0
15/09/2015 00:15:00 START   00:00:00    00:00:00
15/09/2015 00:30:00 START   00:15:00    00:15:00
15/09/2015 00:45:00 START   00:15:00    00:30:00
15/09/2015 01:00:00 START   00:15:00    00:45:00
15/09/2015 01:15:00 START   00:15:00    01:00:00
15/09/2015 01:30:00 START   00:15:00    01:15:00
15/09/2015 01:45:00 START   00:15:00    01:30:00
15/09/2015 02:00:00 START   00:15:00    01:45:00
15/09/2015 02:15:00 STOP    00:00:00    0
15/09/2015 02:30:00 STOP    00:00:00    0
15/09/2015 02:45:00 START   00:00:00    00:00:00
15/09/2015 03:00:00 START   00:15:00    00:15:00
15/09/2015 03:15:00 START   00:15:00    00:30:00
15/09/2015 03:30:00 START   00:15:00    00:45:00
15/09/2015 03:45:00 START   00:15:00    01:00:00
15/09/2015 04:00:00 START   00:15:00    01:15:00
15/09/2015 04:15:00 START   00:15:00    01:30:00
15/09/2015 04:30:00 STOP    00:00:00    0
```

Is there a possibilities to actually filter the data between the STOP pattern so its easier to sum and define the cycle by block?

Answer (score 0):

I've set up an example sheet with a suggested formula for identifying the blocks (cell F2) and a query to summarise the data (cell H1): https://goo.gl/sLbuUT

Comment: Thank you Chris, it work as intended. i wish i could understand more on how the queries work.